# Unescape String doesn't work, it only remove the “escape”

Tags: java, utf-8

```
public ArvinYML replaceOldKey() {
    for(String key : toFile().getKeys()) {
        if(toFile().get(key) != null && !key.startsWith("#") && !key.startsWith(Main.get().getDescription().getName() + "_CMT_")) {
            if(toFile().getConfigurationSection(key) != null) {
                loopKey(key);
            } else {
                String value = "";
                value = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(String.valueOf(config.get(key)));
                data.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's my code, i tried unescapejava and xml, it only remove the escape not encode the utf8

Result:

From

[image: Before]

To
[image: After]

Can someone help me to find what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml11-java.lang.String-) `unescapeXML`

> supports only the five basic XML entities (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos).
>   Does not support DTDs or external entities.

You probably want to use `unescapeXML11`:

> escapeXml11 will escape characters in the following ranges:
>   [#x1-#x8] | [#xB-#xC] | [#xE-#x1F] | [#x7F-#x84] | [#x86-#x9F]
>   ...

Comment: does unescapeJava following ranges #x1-#x8 ?

Comment: unescapeJava unescapes the java escapes, like `\n`, `\t` etc. for details on the other unescape-function see docs following the link in the answer